# REST application using Flask

Tags: python, rest, flask

As part of an introductory project, I have to:

> Code a simple REST application using Flask that offers:
>
> - a POST method to add a name and a phone number to an object in memory
> - a GET method that returns a phone number for a given name, or the whole list of names/phone numbers.

I don't understand what 'in memory' means here. Can anyone give an example of an 'in memory object', and give a simplified version of what the question is asking me to do?

Comment: It means do it in code and just store the objects while the code runs. Normally, this kind of information would be stored in a database; for an academic project, you might consider a file. This is just saying have objects floating around somewhere that they will survive when the request ends.

Comment: Thanks for your response! So just to confirm, would something like user = {'name': 'abc' phone:'123'} be considered an object in memory?

Comment: That's a dictionary (a `dict`), which technically is an object since everything in Python is. But your professor probably means for you to define a new class.